# How can i publish app with different names in play store?

Tags: android

I already published one app in play store.After that i made some changes in the code, now i want to publish that app with different name in play store.How can i release it with out affecting the previous app,so that previous app and present app are showing in play store.

Comment: change package names then u can upload

Answer (score 1):

Before doing any of this please go over to: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/#!?modal_active=none

**This to ensure you are following the policies made by the google play store.**

To achieve what you want you have to change the name and app identifier inside the android manifest.
Afterwards you can just upload it to play store.

Comment: To save manually changing your manifest each time you want to build/release both app's use gradle build flavors to change the applicationId and name.